# How to parse results from google blog search?

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse the number of results from google seach blog. Could somebody please help me!

http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=a&btnG=Search+Blogs

returns a complete page. On the right side you can see (*Results 1 - 10 of about 2,504,830,546  for a. (0.05 seconds)* ).

How could I get **2,504,830,546**???

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: You won't get that much "Sorry, Google does not serve more than 1000 results for any query. (You asked for results starting from 8000.)"

Comment: I think that Jooj wants to get a `2,504,830,546` string. Am I right ?

Comment: Sure, but I need just the results count for further statistics...

Comment: @hsz: YES only the string 2,504,830,546!

Comment: Note the Google Terms of Service: "You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you normally should not parse an HTML file with regexes, in this case you could make an exception (since the page in particular still uses `<font>`, the structure is broken anyway and an XML parser would not help much). This piece of code here assumes that you already have fetched the webpage and put it into the string variable `$webpage_as_string`:

```
preg_match('|Results.+?of +about +\<b\>([0-9,]+)\<\/b\> +for|', $webpage_as_string, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` would contain the result as a string. You'd need to filter out the commas and parse it into a number... Of course, this code would break as soon as Google changes it's site template.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php contains more information on the function, the pattern manual is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: got an error: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot the delimiters on the regex pattern ... php was a while ago for me. fixed it, although I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use their [search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) which includes blog search?

Comment: how could I use this API to get exaclty what I'm needing?

Comment: Check out their documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/ It explains what you need to do and has examples as well.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation but it seems like this API doesn't return "total results number"!

Answer (score 0):

if you have `wget`

```
$ wget -O- -q "http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=a&btnG=Search+Blogs" | awk -vRS="Browse Top Stories|Blog results" -vFS='about|for' '/Results/{gsub(/<b>|<\/b>/,"",$2);print $2}'
 2,493,517,127
```